# custom grid view in android example with data from backend

Tags: android, json, gridview

can anyone please suggest me a tuto or link to create custom grid view to get images from server and cache those images,data should be in json format.
please its very imp for me.I search a lot but could not find proper example.
please help me .

Comment: Do you have your images in a public IP? Such as: http://www.yoururl.com/images/my_image.jpg

Comment: i have my own domain and images are on server and i am gonna parse it by url of images stored in table

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage images from Internet/assets/your phone/much others, then you can use this amazing library [Android universal image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/README.md) here you can find information about this powerful library. This library helps you to load images to your app, even if they are too large, and store them in cache (even if you want to cache the images on disk or just in memory), please read the full article to know exactly how to use it

But, if you want to try it by yourself, you just have to paste this code and have fun testing it as your pleasure

```
public class ImageManageUtils {

/** Tag para logs **/
   private static final String TAG_LOG = ImageManageUtils.class.getName();

public static void displayImage(ImageView view, String path, ImageLoadingListener listener) {
    ImageLoader loader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    try {
        loader.displayImage(path, view, DEFAULT_DISPLAY_IMAGE_OPTIONS, listener);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        loader.clearMemoryCache();
    }
}

public static void displayRoundImage(ImageView view, String path,
                                     ImageLoadingListener listener) {
    ImageLoader loader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    try {
        loader.displayImage(path, view, ROUND_DISPLAY_IMAGE_OPTIONS, listener);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        loader.clearMemoryCache();
    }
}

public static void loadImage(String path, ImageLoadingListener listener) {
    ImageLoader loader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    try {
        loader.loadImage(path, DEFAULT_DISPLAY_IMAGE_OPTIONS, listener);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void removeFromCache(String url) {
    try {
        MemoryCacheUtils.removeFromCache(url, ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache());
        DiskCacheUtils.removeFromCache(url, ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiskCache());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG_LOG, DbdPlusUtils
                .format("Ocurrió un error eliminando la memoria caché de la url [%s]", url), e);
    }
}

private static final DisplayImageOptions.Builder DEFAULT_DISPLAY_IMAGE_OPTIONS_BUIDLER =
        new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300, true, false, false))
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.default_image)
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.default_image).considerExifParams(true)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.default_image).cacheOnDisk(true)
                .cacheInMemory(true).bitmapConfig(Config.ARGB_8888);

private static final DisplayImageOptions DEFAULT_DISPLAY_IMAGE_OPTIONS =
        DEFAULT_DISPLAY_IMAGE_OPTIONS_BUIDLER
                .build();
private static final DisplayImageOptions ROUND_DISPLAY_IMAGE_OPTIONS =
        DEFAULT_DISPLAY_IMAGE_OPTIONS_BUIDLER
                .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(500)).build();
}
```

(sorry for formatting code, I'm from my phone)

The way you can test this class is the following

`ImageManageUtils.displayImage(myImageView, "www.myurl.com/.../myImage.jpg", null)`

Or

`ImageManageUtils.displayImage(myImageView, "file://my_image_path_in_phone", null)`

For your GridView that includes images, here's a good example [link](http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-custom-gridview.html)

I hope this helps

Comment: Antinio thank for this. but i want to have images in custom grid view..cn i use volley library instead?? can u please give me example tutorial link or somthing??

Comment: Oh, sorry, I understood GridLayout. I have modified my answer and change the last link with an example of GridView. About Volley Library, I've never used it, so I can't give you my review. But, Android Universal Image Loader is the #1 image loader used in Android, you should take a look

Comment: sorry but i am not understanding anything here